# Mongodb c# driver Linq query Group by

Tags: c#, linq, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, bson

my mongodb document structure as below: (each document creates for each Term Everyday)

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53da1f0f12f0631d940f97a1"),
    "TermId" : "6cb28ca7-cc64-4b01-8dc5-b5f8d9fac9b5",
    "Term" : "priceless",
    "TotalCount" : 14,
    "date" : ISODate("2014-02-12T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "socialCounts" : [ 
        {
            "Name" : "twitter",
            "Count" : 3
        }, 
        {
            "Name" : "facebook",
            "Count" : 8
        },
        {
            "Name" : "Instagram",
            "Count" : 3
    ]
}
```

I need to get

- sum of Totalcounts for each termId I passed in (grouby each TermID and sum(Totalcount).
- sum of Each Social type count for all Term id's I passed in.

My Methods at present returns just documents

```
public IQueryable<ReportingStats> GetReportingWallStats(List<string> terms, string[] sources, DateTime fr, DateTime to)
        {
            //var socialTypes = sources.ToBsonDocumentArray();
            try
            {
                var entities = from e in this.collection.AsQueryable<Collections.ReportingStats>()
                               where e.date >= fr && e.date <= to && terms.Contains(e.TermId) && e.TotalCount > 0
                               select e;
                var mongoQuery = ((MongoQueryable<ReportingStats>)entities).GetMongoQuery();
                var explain = entities.Explain();
                return entities;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Error("Exception in  method GetReportingWallStats", ex);
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Some one can help me getting the result in below way

dictionaryItem("Term1" 140)

dictionaryItem("Term2" 190)

dictionaryItem("Term3" 100)

dictionaryItem("Term4" 133)

into a dictionary and

dictionaryItem("Facebook" 1440)

dictionaryItem("Twitter" 1640)

dictionaryItem("Instagram" 1940)

into another dictionary in an efficient way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a map reduce query but this will have to be done in Javascript rather than C# as groupby operations are yet to be supported by the .Net driver. An example from the .net/C# tutorial at http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/use-csharp-driver/ :

```
var map =
"function() {" +
"    for (var key in this) {" +
"        emit(key, { count : 1 });" +
"    }" +
"}";

var reduce =
"function(key, emits) {" +
"    total = 0;" +
"    for (var i in emits) {" +
"        total += emits[i].count;" +
"    }" +
"    return { count : total };" +
"}";

var mr = collection.MapReduce(map, reduce);
foreach (var document in mr.GetResults()) {
    Console.WriteLine(document.ToJson());
}
```

[Another example at Ode to Code](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2012/03/19/a-simple-mapreduce-with-mongodb-and-c.aspx)